# Unexpected token If I Run "gulp" command

Tags: laravel, vue.js, gulp, nvm, laravel-elixir

```
gulp -v

  CLI version:2.3.0 , 
  Local version:3.9.1

nvm version :
  5.6.0
```

If I run gulp command then this error, How can I solve this issue?

> [SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...]

Comment: Please share the whole error message here.

Comment: There's not enough information here to give us any idea as to what might be wrong.

Comment: Sorry to say, I if I run the gulp command  it returns only 
[SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...] nothing else!!

Comment: At least show your gulpfile.js.  And what task is running when it errors?

Comment: Run gulp command first time then it will show error